# swift Logical Operators orderly

Tags: swift

```
func addOne() -> Bool {
    x += 1
    print("111")
    return true
}

if true || addOne() && addOne() && addOne(){
    print("open the door")
} else {
    print("can't open the door")
}
```

I knew that logical operators are calculated from left to right but in this case `addOne` function doesn't called in this condition.

So `x` value is `0` and I expected `2` How to solve this logical operators order?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Anything after `if true || ` is ignored.

Comment: Also note that `&&` has higher priority than `||`. Your condition means `true || (addOne() && addOne() && addOne())`

Comment: I also wonder why you expect `x` to be 2 if you (try to) increment it *three* times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called [**Short-circuit Evaluation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and it means when a statement stops evaluation as soon as an outcome is determined. The parts of an expression containing `&&` or `||` operators are evaluated only until it’s known whether the condition is true or false. This speeds up the execution of expression evaluation.

So in your code `true || addOne() && addOne() && addOne()` is known to be `true` as soon as you find `true` in your expression. In general `true || whatever` will always be true, so there is no need to evaluate `whatever`.

`&&` has precedence over `||` so :

```
true || addOne() && addOne() && addOne()
```

is equivalent to :

```
true || (addOne() && addOne() && addOne())
```

And we already know that `true` **OR** `whatever` is true, so `whatever` won't be evaluated.

To change the default precedence in your expression use parentheses where you see fit. For example:

```
(true || addOne()) && (addOne() && addOne())
```

In this case, the first `addOne()` won't be evaluated, But the second and third will be, since `true` **AND** `something` is `something`. And thus, in this case, x would be equal to 2 (supposing that initially x = 0).

Here is a final example (I suppose you get it by now, if not let me know in the comments):

```
if (true || addOne() && addOne())   &&   addOne()
```

In this case, there is an **OR** between `true` and `addOne() && addOne()`. Without evaluating `addOne() && addOne()` we already know that `true || addOne() && addOne()` is `true`. So the expression could be simplified to `true && addOne()`. Here we have to evaluate `addOne()`, which means, `x` will equal `1`.

---

### Edit

Swift operators belong to *Precedence Groups* (or levels) which are used to decide which operation has more priority in the evaluation of an expression. A higher precedence level means more priority.

The logical AND `&&` belongs to the **LogicalConjunctionPrecedence** group, which has a higher precedence than the **LogicalDisjunctionPrecedence** group, to which the logical OR `||` belongs to. And thus `&&` has more precedence than `||`.

To learn more about operator precedence groups/levels, have a look right at the bottom of [this](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/e5abbe8afafa9b1dd3e32771b497e4e0c48d7864/stdlib/public/core/Policy.swift), or  [that](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/6fc4cef671947d1d2482951853f7f82854473d91/docs/archive/LangRefNew.rst).

Comment: Thank you I can find && operator has a higher precedence than || in  Swift document

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

As @Sulthan said, the `&&` operator has a higher precedence than `||`, so

```
 true || addOne() && addOne() && addOne()
```

is equivalent to

```
true || (addOne() && addOne() && addOne())
```

Then note that the boolean operators are “short-circuiting:” If the left operand
of `||` evaluates to `true` then the right operand is not evaluated at all.
Well, `true` is true, and that's why `addOne()` is never called.

If you change it to

```
(true || addOne()) && addOne() && addOne()
```

then the function would be called twice ...

See [Operator Declarations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library/operator_declarations) for more information about operator precedence.

Comment: Thank you I can find && operator has a higher precedence than || in  Swift document